# Inheritance in java using array list

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I'm using simple inheritance in java but i'm not able to get the values from the parent class. I'm following all the standards in java but it's returning empty. I know in order to access the parents class we've to use `super` keyword. But i'm getting an empty array for `price_ofProducts` in my program. Where I'm getting things wrong? Need a direction. Here's my code:

```
package project;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Product p = new Product();
    p.name_ofProducts.add("laptop");
    p.price_ofProducts.add(5000);
    p.Quantity_ofProducts.add(3);
    p.name_ofProductCompany.add("dell");
    p.Product_idNumber.add(287);
    
    p.name_ofProducts.add("Moblie");
    p.price_ofProducts.add(3000);
    p.Quantity_ofProducts.add(3);
    p.name_ofProductCompany.add("Nokia");
    p.Product_idNumber.add(3567);
    
    p.name_ofProducts.add("I pad");
    p.price_ofProducts.add(9000);
    p.Quantity_ofProducts.add(5);
    p.name_ofProductCompany.add("hp");
    p.Product_idNumber.add(7845);
    
    p.name_ofProducts.add("ispot");
    p.price_ofProducts.add(600);
    p.Quantity_ofProducts.add(2);
    p.name_ofProductCompany.add("Nokia");
    p.Product_idNumber.add(233);
    
    p.name_ofProducts.add("Oven");
    p.price_ofProducts.add(10000);
    p.Quantity_ofProducts.add(5);
    p.name_ofProductCompany.add("Orient");
    p.Product_idNumber.add(766);
    
    p.name_ofProducts.add("AC");
    p.price_ofProducts.add(15000);
    p.Quantity_ofProducts.add(5);
    p.name_ofProductCompany.add("Haier");
    p.Product_idNumber.add(577);
    
    p.dispalyProduct();
    
//        System.out.println("Price of Products Array: " + p.price_ofProducts.get(1));
    Transaction tr1 = new Transaction();
    tr1.Product_Number();
    
    //p.displayProduct();
    
}
}
```

My Product:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package project;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author zfhas
 */
public class Product {
    
        protected int Quantity; 
    protected int price;
    protected String name;
    protected int id;
    protected String company;
    protected ArrayList<String> name_ofProducts= new ArrayList<String>();
        
    protected ArrayList<Integer> price_ofProducts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    protected ArrayList<Integer> Quantity_ofProducts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    protected ArrayList<String> name_ofProductCompany = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected ArrayList<Integer> Product_idNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    public Product()
    {
            
    }
    public Product(int price, String name, int Quantity, String company, int id) 
    {
        
        this.Quantity=Quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.company=company;
        this.id=id;
        
    }

    Product(ArrayList<Integer> price_ofProducts) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    // Setter Method
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
        
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int Quantity)
    {
        this.Quantity=Quantity;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company)
    {
        this.company=company;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
    // Getter Methods
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }   
    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return Quantity;
    }
    public String getCompany()
    {
        return company;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void dispalyProduct()
    {
        System.out.println("Name\tPrices\tQuantity\tcompany\tid_no");
        for(int i=0;i<name_ofProducts.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println((i+1)+")"+name_ofProducts.get(i)+""+price_ofProducts.get(i)+"\t"+Quantity_ofProducts.get(i)+"\t"+name_ofProductCompany.get(i)+"\t"+Product_idNumber.get(i));
        }
        
    }
}
```

My Transaction class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package project;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author zfhas
 */
public class Transaction extends Product{   
    private int product_Number;
    private int calculation;
    public Transaction()
    {
             
    }
    
    public void setProduct_Number(int product_Number)
    {
        this.product_Number=product_Number;
        
    }
    public int getProduct_Number()
    {
        return product_Number;
    }
    
    //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void Product_Number()
    {
                /*
                    Products Display
                */
        dispalyProduct();
                
                /*
                    Declaring Variables
                */
        int quantity;
        int product_number=0;
                /*
                    Performing Transaction
                */
        System.out.println("Enter the Number of product that you want to parchased");
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        product_number= Input.nextInt();
                
        System.out.println("Product Number is: "+product_number);
        System.out.println("Enter Quantity");
        quantity = Input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Quantity Entered "+quantity);
        
        //System.out.println(super.price_ofProducts);
        switch (product_number)
        {
            case 1:
                try {

                    System.out.println("Price of Product: " + super.price_ofProducts.get(1-1));
                    calculation = super.price_ofProducts.get(1-1);
                    System.out.println(calculation);
                    calculation(calculation,quantity);
                    System.out.println("It works.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Price of Product: " + super.price_ofProducts.get(2-1));
                    calculation = super.price_ofProducts.get(2-1);
                    calculation(calculation,quantity);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                try{
                    
                    System.out.println(super.price_ofProducts.get(3-1));
                    calculation= super.price_ofProducts.get(3-1);
                    calculation(calculation,quantity);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                try{
                    calculation= super.price_ofProducts.get(4-1);
                    calculation(calculation,quantity);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                try{
                    calculation=super.price_ofProducts.get(5-1);
                    calculation(calculation,quantity);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                try{
                    calculation=super.price_ofProducts.get(6-1);
                    calculation(calculation,quantity);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                }
                break;      
            default:
                System.out.println("you entered wrong number");
                break;
        }
    }
        public void calculation(int a, int b)
    {
            int total;
            total = a*b;
            billDisplay(total);
    }
    public void billDisplay(int total)
    {
            System.out.println("your total bill = "+total);
            billrecive(total);
    }
    public void billrecive(int total)
    {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int enteredMoney=Input.nextInt();
            int i=0;
            while(i>1)
            {   
                if(enteredMoney==total)
                {
                    displayRecipt();
                    break;
                }
                else if (enteredMoney<total)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter More= ");
                    int enteredMoney1=Input.nextInt();
                    enteredMoney+=enteredMoney1;
                    continue;
                }   
                else if(enteredMoney>total)
                {
                    enteredMoney=enteredMoney-total;
                    System.out.println("Your remaining are : "+enteredMoney);
                    displayRecipt();
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
        public void displayRecipt()
        {
                System.out.println("billing done");
                dispalyProduct();
        }
    public void addProduts(String name,int price,int quantity,String company, int id)
    {
        name_ofProducts.add(name);
        price_ofProducts.add(price);
        Quantity_ofProducts.add(quantity);
        name_ofProductCompany.add(company);
        Product_idNumber.add(id);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Just as a starting note - this seems like a ... less than optimal way to define your class, unless you _really_ want it to be this way. You've designed it so that each instance of a product has not only it's own data (name, price, qty, etc.) but also a (disassociated?) list of names, prices, quantities, etc? Is there a reason you're not handling the lists outside of the ```Product``` class to represent that, assuming these are intended to be common real world products?

Comment: it's just for learning purpose. And don't represent any real world products or used in real world solution.

Comment: Second note - what makes ```Transaction``` feasible as a child of ```Product```? Subclasses generally has an "is a" relationship with the parent. That is, you are saying that ```Transaction``` is a ```Product```. I think you probably want to rethink that into a "has a" relationship. That is, a ```Transaction``` would contain a member variable of type ```Product``` (or likely a list of ```Product```s)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to take that at face value and check the issue =)

Comment: so it means it's due to my incorrect relations of Transaction class and my product class correct?

Comment: I run your main class and see prices output. What error are you seeing and how can I replicate it?

Comment: press 1 and then 1 to replicate the problem.  It's asking for a user's input.

Comment: ah ok, now I see. Your problem is that you add all the items into ```Product p``` and then create a new ```Transaction tr1```. ```tr1``` has no visibility into the data present in the ```p```. You're mixing up inheritance and object visibility. Just because ```tr1``` is a ```Product``` (because ```Transaction``` inherits from ```Product```) doesn't mean that this particular instance can see any other ```Product``` or ```Transaction``` instance data

Comment: Side note: you are going against a lot of Java conventions/best practices here and doing a lot of things you should *never* do in Java, such as using underscores and capitalized variable names (`Quantity` should be `quantity`, `Product_idNumber` should be written as `productIdNumber` but you shouldn't be repeating the class/datatype name in your attribute names at all, so it should really be `id`, etc). It's also really unclear why you have all these array list associations for other individual Product attributes. This is not proper object design. I recommend getting a book like HeadFirst Java

Comment: Java naming conventions have most names use camelCase without underlines. Classes start with upper case letters; methods and variables start with lower case letters (quantity, productIdNumber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product p` and `Transaction tr1` are two completely separate object instances.

You set up all of your products in `p` and then query the user via `tr1`. `tr1` doesn't have any of the same product data (or any data at all) when you ask the user which one to pick. It only displays the products at all because you call `p.dispalyProduct`